# Javascript/Ajax/Jquery Dynamically calculation form on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a small form which is going to be populated from Mysql database and human input. What I want to do is calculate 2 other fields based on the other ones.

Example Form:

- Indicator (MySQL) (a dropdown)
- Hour Equivalent (MySQL)
- SKS  Equivalent (MySQL)
- Amount (User)
- Hour Total (Amount*Hour Equivalent)
- SKS Total (Amount*SKS Equivalent)
- Submit (Button to save into table)

This is an example for the calculation operation that I try to solve

- Indicator = A
- Hour Equivalent = 20
- SKS  Equivalent = 15
- Amount = 2
- Hour Total (Amount*Hour Equivalent) = 40
- SKS Total (Amount*SKS Equivalent) = 30

I have searched around and try some of solutions but I can’t quite find what I am looking for, and my skills are not really good in Javascript/Ajax/Jquery so I haven't able to do  anything to work, although I have tried miserably.

How to do it?

This is the HTML Form

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>PSC Achievement</legend>
<!-- Button Drop Down -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="buttondropdown">Indicator</label>
         <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Choose
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        </ul>
      </div>
   
  <label for="txtsks">SKS Equivalent</label>  
  <input id="txtsks" name="txtSks" type="text">
    
  <label for="txtjam">Hour Equivalent </label>  
  <input id="txtjam" name="txtHour"type="text">
  
  <label for="textjml">Amount</label>  
  <input id="textjml" name="txtAmount" type="text">

  <label for="Totalhour">Hour Total</label>  
  <input id="Totalhour" name="Totalhour" type="text">  
 
  <label for="Totalsks">SKS Total</label>  
  <input id="Totalsks" name="Totalsks" type="text">
    
  <label for="btn_submit"></label>
  <button id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What kink of calculations do you need? Try to write mini-sample of start state and end state.

Comment: okay, I'll already edit and gave the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution here : https://jsfiddle.net/tv94prmu/ . Calc function is a result of change event. Result will be displayed after one of fields will be filled

```
$(function(){
$('#txtsks,#txtjam,#textjml').change(function(){
calc();
})
function calc(){
    $('#Totalhour').val(parseInt($('#txtjam').val())*parseInt($('#textjml').val()))

  $('#Totalsks').val(parseInt($('#txtsks').val())*parseInt($('#textjml').val()))

}
})
```

Also, you need to include jquery library to page.

Answer (score 1):

If i got your answer correctly.

Your need to provide more info about your code, but, as far as i understood.. u need to add event handlers for your form (as shown below).

- Please note that you have set some of the id's of your elements with an uppercase and some with camelCase. which is bad practice, for better practie, decide on a pattern that you are working at.

  It will be easier to handle when you are getting back to your code in the future.

```js
txtsks.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
/* call SKS Equivalent function */
}, true);

txtjam.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
/* call Hour Equivalent function */
}, true);

textjml.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
/* call Amount (User) function */
}, true);

Totalhour.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
/* call Hour Total (Amount*Hour Equivalent) function */
}, true);

Totalsks.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
/* call SKS Total (Amount*SKS Equivalent) function */
}, true);

btn_submit.addEventListener("click", function ( event ) {
  /* call Submit(Button to save into table) function */
  });
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>PSC Achievement</legend>
<!-- Button Drop Down -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="buttondropdown">Indicator</label>
         <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Choose
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        </ul>
      </div>
   
  <label for="txtsks">SKS Equivalent</label>  
  <input id="txtsks" name="txtSks" type="text">
    
  <label for="txtjam">Hour Equivalent </label>  
  <input id="txtjam" name="txtHour"type="text">
  
  <label for="textjml">Amount</label>  
  <input id="textjml" name="txtAmount" type="text">

  <label for="Totalhour">Hour Total</label>  
  <input id="Totalhour" name="Totalhour" type="text">  
 
  <label for="Totalsks">SKS Total</label>  
  <input id="Totalsks" name="Totalsks" type="text">
    
  <label for="btn_submit"></label>
  <button id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```